# Is it possible to speedup FileProviderEnumerator for many files?

Tags: swift, fileprovider, fileprovider-extension

I'm creating FileProvider extension for MacOS. In my case I have a remote folder with a lots of small files (~50k).

If I trying to open file directly by known name (for example with a `cat` in terminal), FileProvider asks listing of directory first — invokes `enumerator`, and only then `fetchContents`.

It's wouldn't be a problem if `enumerateItems` will be fast. If enumerate all 50k items, macOS kills extension. So I did [batching](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/content_and_change_tracking/defining_your_file_provider_s_content). And it works, but **extremely slow**. My system suggests 200 items in a batch (observer's `suggestedPageSize` property), `enumerateItems` invokes about once per second. More than 4 minutes to get a list files in directory! Without any network requests, because list is cached.

Is it possible to speedup `NSFileProviderEnumerator`? Or tell FileProvider to invoke `fetchContents` without parent enumerating? Maybe any hacks?

```
let pageSize: Int64 = Int64(observer.suggestedPageSize ?? 256)
let sliceFrom: Int64 = page.toInt64()
var sliceTo: Int64 = 0
var nextPage: NSFileProviderPage? = nil
var items: [FileProviderItem] = []
var content = item.getChildItems() ?? []  // cached
    
if content.count >= sliceFrom + pageSize {
    sliceTo = sliceFrom + pageSize - 1
    nextPage = NSFileProviderPage(sliceTo + 1)
}
else {
    sliceTo = Int64(content.count - 1)
}

content.enumerated().filter({ $0.offset >= sliceFrom && $0.offset <= sliceTo}).forEach {
    (_, file) in
    let itemIdentifier = FileProviderItem.fileToItemIdentifier(object: file)
    let childItem = FileProviderItemRepository.shared.getItem(identifier: itemIdentifier)
    items.append(childItem)
}

observer.didEnumerate(items)
observer.finishEnumerating(upTo: nextPage)
```